# Nokogiri- Parsing HTML <a href> and displaying only part of the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

So basically I am scraping a website, and I want to display only part of the address. For instance, if it is www.yadaya.com/nyc/sales/manhattan and I want to only put "sales" in a hash or an array.

```
{
  :listing_class => listings.css('a').text
}
```

That will give me the whole URL. Would I want to gsub to get the partial output?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to do regexp to get that.

Comment: Do you always want the second to last path element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are dealing with URLs, you should start with URI, then, to mess with the path, switch to using `File.dirname` and/or `File.basename`:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse('http://www.yadaya.com/nyc/sales/manhattan')
dir = File.dirname(uri.path).split('/').last
```

which sets `dir` to `"sales"`.

No regex is needed, except what `parse` and `split` do internally.

Using that in your code's context:

```
File.dirname(URI.parse(listings.css('a').text).path).split('/').last
```

but, personally, I'd break that into two lines for clarity and readability, which translate into easier maintenance.

A warning though:

```
listings.css('a')
```

returns a NodeSet, which is akin to an Array. If the DOM you are searching has multiple `<a>` tags, you will get more than one Node being passed to `text`, which will then be concatenated into the text you are treating as a URL. That's a bug in waiting:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<div><a href="foo">foo</a><a href="bar">bar</a></div>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.at('div').css('a').text
```

Which results in:

```
"foobar"
```

Instead, your code needs to be:

```
listings.at('a')
```

or

```
listings.at_css('a')
```

so only one node is returned. In the context of my sample code:

```
doc.at('div').at('a').text
# => "foo"
```

Even if the code that sets up `listings` only results in a single `<a>` node being visible, use `at` or `at_css` for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the full URL using `listings.css('a').text`, you could parse out a section of the path using a combination of the [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class and a regular expression, using something like the following:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(listings.css('a').text)
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x007f91a39255b8 URL:http://www.yadaya.com/nyc/sales/manhattan>

match = %r{^/nyc/([^/]+)/}.match(uri.path)
 => #<MatchData "/nyc/sales/" 1:"sales">

match[1]
 => "sales"
```

You may need to tweak the regular expression to meet your needs, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I am looking for. On a side note, any idea why output would be #<Listing:0x007fd85c9e9ee0>? I have multiple keys/values in my hash.

Comment: What is outputting that? `listings.css('a').text ` ?